# Get a specific field in a document in Firestore using Angular

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm doing a web application in Angular 6 with Angularfire2 and I save the user's personal information in Firestore, like first name, last name, gender, etc..

My user model is:

```
export interface User {
  firstName: string;
  secondName: string;
  firstSurname: string;
  secondSurname: string;
  emailAddress: string;
  gender: string;
  dateOfBirth: Date;
}

export interface UserId extends User {
  id: string;
}
```

I have a service called FirestoreService with this:

```
export class FirestoreService {

  usersCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<User>;
  userDocument: AngularFirestoreDocument<User>;
  users: Observable<User[]>;

  constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore
  ) {
    // Users
    this.usersCollection = afs.collection<User>('users');
    this.users = this.usersCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as User;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return {id, ...data};
      }))
    );
  }

  getUser(uid: string) {
    return this.usersCollection.doc(uid).get();
  }
}
```

I also have tried:

```
getUser(uid: string) {
    this.usersCollection.doc(uid).ref.get().then(doc => {
      if (doc.exists) {
        return doc.data();
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

Inside of my component, I need specifically the **firstName** of the user to show it on the screen but, if I can grab all the information is better.

In my component I have:

```
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  userData: any;
  firstName: string;
  firstSurname: string;

  constructor(private firestoreService: FirestoreService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userData = this.firestoreService.getUser('WeGPHreNXIefLwsBsJpRj4txO4S2');
    console.log(this.userData);
  }
}
```

Right now, all I get in console is weird things, not any real data of the user. I have tried changing the `getUser` method of the service to this:

```
getUser(uid: string) {
    return this.usersCollection.doc(uid).valueChanges();
}
```

What I want is to be able to access to the user's information to show  it in my component's template like: `{{firstName}}` or maybe using my model like `{{user.firstName}}`, I'm not sure which one is the best approach. I have saw other solutions on the forum but none of them seems to help me.